# How to have a bright white text on image overlay in css?

Tags: css

Here is a code to have a text and an overlay on an image:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* for IE 6 */
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

  <img src="https://www.monsitexemple.fr/lcee/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/mil2-1-300x225.jpg">
  <h2>Hello</h2>

</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ed5c5u8h/)

As you can see,
the text in white get affected by the opacity of the overlay. So my question is: how do you keep the text to be "bright" i.e not affected by opacity ?

Comment: it's not bright because you add a white background behind it. You can change the color of the `<h2>` when `<img>` is hovered like so: https://jsfiddle.net/yg4712da/

Comment: @Ihazkode In your code if I change the hover+h2 color from black to white, the text is still with opacity...

Comment: actually it is full bright, but because you use white on white it does not appear good try to add text-shadow to h2 tag, it will distinguish the title from background when the opacity is decreased

Comment: The background behind the image is white. When you set the opacity of the image to `.2` on hover, you make the image translucent. The `<h2>` element is not affected. It just doesn't show because the background behind it washes the contrast since it's of a similar color.  Look what happens when the background behind the image is black and we leave `<h2>` unmodified here https://jsfiddle.net/oyjqL4q3/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is set a div for the image, and make the background of it black. This way the background stays dark and text is visible, but the image fades out.

I added one line of css to your fiddle, you'd just need to make the div itself and style it properly. I don't know if your div is responsive or static width.

https://jsfiddle.net/ed5c5u8h/

```
<div class="image">

  <div class="the_image">
    <img src="https://www.monsitexemple.fr/lcee/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/mil2-1-300x225.jpg">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the text is not affected by de opacity. It's only an optical effect.
Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ed5c5u8h/5/ whith different color than white.

```
  .image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

img:hover{opacity:0.01;}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   color:#ff5555;
   top: 20px; 
   left: 100px; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```